# react-native-firebase android app closes when message comes in

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have added react-native-firebase to my app, but when a message is sent from either the Firebase console or Postman, the app closes. When I look at either the debug window or use react-native log-android, there are no error message, the app simply closes. No information is provided.

my primary file is called Base.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Animated, Dimensions, StyleSheet, Platform, Image, Text, View, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import rnfirebase, { Notification, RemoteMessage, NotificationOpen } from 'react-native-firebase';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info-2';
import { Button, CardSection, Card } from './components/common';
import { getUserInfo, storeToken } from './actions';

const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const GLOBAL = require('./Globals');

class Base extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      emergencyNotification: '',
      user:{
        name: 'nSideMobileAdmin'
      }
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    getUserInfo();
    rnfirebase.messaging().getToken().then((fcmToken) => {
      if (fcmToken !== null) {
        GLOBAL.FCMTOKEN = fcmToken;
        console.log(`Token obtained: ${fcmToken}`);
        if (!GLOBAL.TOKENSTORED) {
            GLOBAL.TOKENSTORED = true;
            storeToken(fcmToken, 'General')
          }
        AsyncStorage.setItem('rnfb-token', fcmToken);
      } else {
        console.log('Unable to get token.');
      }

      rnfirebase.messaging().hasPermission().then((enabled) => {
        if (enabled) {
          console.log(`Messaging Enabled`);
          const channel = new rnfirebase.notifications.Android.Channel('nSideMobile', 'nSide Channel', rnfirebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max)
            .setDescription('nSide Mobile Channel');

          // Create the channel
          rnfirebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);
          this.messageListener = rnfirebase.messaging().onMessage((message: RemoteMessage) => {
            console.log(`Message Recieved: ${JSON.stringify(message)}`);
            console.log(`GLOBAL NOTIFICATION: ${JSON.stringify(message)}`);
          });
        } else {
          try {
            rnfirebase.messaging().requestPermission().then((response) => {
              console.log('User is authorized');
            });
          } catch (error) {
              console.log('User has rejected permissions');
          }
        }
      //
      //   this.notificationDisplayedListener = rnfirebase.notifications().onNotificationDisplayed((notification: Notification) => {
      //     console.log(`Notification Displayed: ${JSON.stringify(notification.body)}`);
      //     pushNotification(notification, this.state.user);
      //     this.setState({ emergencyNotification: notification });
      //     //Actions.Emergency();
      //   });
      //   this.notificationListener = rnfirebase.notifications().onNotification((notification: Notification) => {
      //     pushNotification(notification, this.state.user);
      //     this.setState({ emergencyNotification: notification });
      //     //Actions.Emergency();
      //   });
      //   this.notificationOpenedListener = rnfirebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen: NotificationOpen) => {
      //     const action = notificationOpen.action;
      //     const notification: Notification = notificationOpen.notification;
      //     console.log(`App Opened by Notification with message: : ${notification.body}`);
      //     pushNotification(notification, this.state.user);
      //     this.setState({ emergencyNotification: notification });
      //     //Actions.Emergency();
      //   });
      //   rnfirebase.notifications().getInitialNotification().then((notificationOpen) => {
      //     if (notificationOpen) {
      //       const action = notificationOpen.action;
      //       const notification: Notification = notificationOpen.notification;
      //       console.log(`App Opened by Initial Notification with Message: : ${notification.body}`);
      //       pushNotification(notification, this.state.user);
      //       this.setState({ emergencyNotification: notification });
      //       //Actions.Emergency();
      //     }
      //   });
      });
    });
  }

  pushNotification(notification, user){
      console.log(`${JSON.stringify(user)}`);
      pushNotification(notification, user);
  }

  async onLoginButtonPress() {
    try {
      const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
      if (token === null || token === 'LoggedOut') {
          Actions.login();
      } else {
        console.log('LoggedIn');
        GLOBAL.USER.token = token;
        GLOBAL.USER.id = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userID');
        //console.log(`Logged in ${GLOBAL.USER.id} with token: ${GLOBAL.USER.token}`);
        Actions.menu();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      //We'll deal with the error later
    }
  }

  onRegisterButtonPress() {
      Actions.register();
  }

  onChatButtonPress() {
      Actions.chatLogin();
  }
  getDeviceInfo() {
    const deviceName = DeviceInfo.getDeviceId();
    this.setState(deviceName: deviceName);
  }
  componeWillUnmount() {
    this.onTokenRefreshListener();
    this.messageListener();
    this.notificationDisplayedListener();
    this.notificationListener();
    this.notificationOpenedListener();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Card>
        <CardSection>
          <Image
            source={require('../assets//hsschool.jpg')}
            style={{ width: SCREEN_WIDTH, height: SCREEN_WIDTH }}
          />
        </CardSection>
        <CardSection>
          <Image
            source={require('../assets/logo.jpg')}
            style={{ width: SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.95, height: SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.255 }}
          />
        </CardSection>
        <CardSection>
            <Button onPressAction={this.onLoginButtonPress.bind(this)}>
              Login
            </Button>
            <Button onPressAction={this.onRegisterButtonPress.bind(this)}>
              Register
            </Button>
            <Button onPressAction={this.onChatButtonPress.bind(this)}>
              Chat
            </Button>
        </CardSection>
      <View style={styles.modules}>
        <Text style={styles.modulesHeader}>The following Firebase modules are enabled:</Text>
        {rnfirebase.admob.nativeModuleExists && <Text style={styles.module}>Admob</Text>}
        {rnfirebase.analytics.nativeModuleExists && <Text style={styles.module}>Analytics</Text>}
        {rnfirebase.auth.nativeModuleExists && <Text style={styles.module}>Authentication</Text>}
        {rnfirebase.firestore.nativeModuleExists && <Text style={styles.module}>Cloud Firestore</Text>}
        {rnfirebase.messaging.nativeModuleExists && <Text style={styles.module}>Cloud Messaging</Text>}
        {rnfirebase.links.nativeModuleExists && <Text style={styles.module}>Dynamic Links</Text>}
        {rnfirebase.iid.nativeModuleExists && <Text style={styles.module}>Instance ID</Text>}
        {rnfirebase.notifications.nativeModuleExists && <Text style={styles.module}>Notifications</Text>}
        {rnfirebase.perf.nativeModuleExists && <Text style={styles.module}>Performance Monitoring</Text>}
        {rnfirebase.database.nativeModuleExists && <Text style={styles.module}>Realtime Database</Text>}
        {rnfirebase.config.nativeModuleExists && <Text style={styles.module}>Remote Config</Text>}
        {rnfirebase.storage.nativeModuleExists && <Text style={styles.module}>Storage</Text>}
      </View>
    </Card>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const {
    emergencyNotification } = state.session;
  return {
    emergencyNotification };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  getUserInfo: () => {
    dispatch(getUserInfo());
  },
  storeToken: () => {
    storeToken(storeToken());
  }
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Base);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  modules: {
    margin: 20,
    transform: [{ scale: 0 }]
  },
  module: {
    fontSize: 14,
    marginTop: 4,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  cardStyle: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 2,
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.3,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation: 1,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    marginTop: 10
  }
});
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nsidemobile",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-beta",
    "babel-jest": "22.0.6",
    "fs-extra": "^4.0.2",
    "jest": "^23.2.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0",
    "replace-in-file": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "rename": "node ./bin/rename.js",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "eslint-config-rallycoding": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "fbjs": "^0.8.16",
    "firebase": "^5.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "node-fetch": "^2.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-native": "^0.56.0",
    "react-native-camera-kit": "^6.2.6",
    "react-native-communications": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-device-info-2": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-firebase": "^4.3.6",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.11.15",
    "react-native-google-signin": "git+https://github.com/invertase/react-native-google-signin.git#v0.12.1",
    "react-native-image-base64": "^0.1.3",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.21.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-push-notifications": "^3.0.10",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.31",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^5.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.11.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^3.4.2"
  }
}
```

my Application.js:

```
package io.nside.nsidemobile;

import android.app.Application;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.wix.RNCameraKit.RNCameraKitPackage;
import fr.snapp.imagebase64.RNImgToBase64Package;
import fr.bamlab.rnimageresizer.ImageResizerPackage;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.rnfs.RNFSPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;
// optional packages - add/remove as appropriate
import io.invertase.firebase.admob.RNFirebaseAdMobPackage; //Firebase AdMob
import io.invertase.firebase.analytics.RNFirebaseAnalyticsPackage; // Firebase Analytics
import io.invertase.firebase.auth.RNFirebaseAuthPackage; // Firebase Auth
import io.invertase.firebase.config.RNFirebaseRemoteConfigPackage; // Firebase Remote Config
import io.invertase.firebase.database.RNFirebaseDatabasePackage; // Firebase Realtime Database
import io.invertase.firebase.firestore.RNFirebaseFirestorePackage; // Firebase Firestore
import io.invertase.firebase.instanceid.RNFirebaseInstanceIdPackage; // Firebase Instance ID
import io.invertase.firebase.links.RNFirebaseLinksPackage; // Firebase Dynamic Links
import io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingPackage; // Firebase Cloud Messaging
import io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage; // Firebase Notifications
import io.invertase.firebase.perf.RNFirebasePerformancePackage; // Firebase Performance
import io.invertase.firebase.storage.RNFirebaseStoragePackage; // Firebase Storage
import io.invertase.firebase.fabric.crashlytics.RNFirebaseCrashlyticsPackage; // Crashlytics

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        new MainReactPackage(),
        new VectorIconsPackage(),
        new RNFSPackage(),
        new ImageResizerPackage(),
        new MapsPackage(),
        new RNFirebasePackage(),
        // add/remove these packages as appropriate
        new RNFirebaseAdMobPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseAnalyticsPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseAuthPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseCrashlyticsPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseDatabasePackage(),
        new RNFirebaseFirestorePackage(),
        new RNFirebaseInstanceIdPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseLinksPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseMessagingPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage(),
        new RNFirebasePerformancePackage(),
        new RNFirebaseRemoteConfigPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseStoragePackage(),
        new RNCameraKitPackage()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="io.nside.nsidemobile"
    android:versionCode="1"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <permission
       android:name="io.nside.nsidemobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
       android:protectionLevel="signature" />
   <uses-permission android:name="io.nside.nsidemobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
      <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
      </service>
      <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
      </service>
      <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService" />
      <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="io.nside.nsidemobile" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationRegistrationService"/>
        <service
            android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <meta-data
          tools:replace="android:value"
          android:name="android.support.VERSION"
          android:value="25.3.1" />
          <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAMsevtE97707k9dzhgvGuMbmK6SHN6I-Q"/>
            <!-- Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Does that occurs only then app is in background? As well how do u sent messages, notification or data message?

Comment: It occurs with the app is in the foreground, and I've tried to send them both thru Firebase and through Postman, as both notification and as data.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like something I faced with admob firebase's module.

Try comment all the code linked to admob and then rebuild.
If problem disappear you should verify firebase admob configuration looking at app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml contains following replacing your application ID from AdMob console :

```
<meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value="ca-app-pub.............."/> 
<uses-library
    android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

Here you will find usefull details on this topic
https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/admob/android

See you